# Векторная или растровая графика для 2D игры?

Tags: анимация, разработка-игр, графика, photoshop

Делаю **2D** игру на движке *Unity*, определился, что анимация для персонажей будет скелетной и реализовано с помощью расширения *Anime2D*, но вот где рисовать сами спрайты озадачился. Будет это растровое изображение(использование *photoshop*), или векторное.

Поэтому вопросы:

1. В каких случаях используют векторную, а в каких растровую? (например
   для персонажей рисуют векторную, а для фонов и декораций растровую)
2. И какие самые популярные и лучшие инструменты для этого
   используются(например для растровой насколько я понял *adobe
   photoshop* мастхев), а для векторной графики?
3. Есть разница в создании анимации при использовании растрового или
   векторной графики?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще юнити из коробки,на сколько мне извесно, не имеет возможности использовать векторную графику. А значит, предпочтительнее растовая, как поддерживаемая по дефолту.

1. Если расчитываешь что будут играть на больших расширениях экрана и не на мобилах) Векторная графика в любом случае будет более требовательна к железу. Тем более если работать со сторонними ассетами, которые не факт что написаны нормально.
2. Как ни странно -- любой векторный редактор, формат которого поддерживает выбранный ассет юнити. Скорее всего файлы адоб Илюстратора будут поддерживатся.
3. Понятия не имею. Не пробовал

Comment: Я так понял тут как и с скелетной и покадровой анимацией, векторная как и скелетная меньше жрет памяти и лучше по качеству, но требовательна к CPU, так?
Короче говоря в большинстве мобильных приложениях используют именно растровую графику?
Игру планирую делать на мобилки, андроид, ios, естесна и на планшеты пойдет, но в любом случае я так понял мне стоит остановится именно на растровой графике, и именно в фотошопе?
@Andrew

Comment: да, ведь в случае с растовой тебе не нужны вычисления, фактически. а в векторной тебе нужно вычислять как проставить пиксели при прорисовке(растеризация векторной графики). Да, почти все используют растовую. Кроме того растовая графика может иметь больше контроля над тенями и деталями. Векторная имеет свои минуса -- ведь теней/деталей там, фактически не делают. А если и делают то очень упрощенные.

Comment: Thank you very much!)) @Andrew